# Why using nameless object gives error?

Tags: java, c++, compiler-errors, language-features

I am new to Java (working on Android). I have seen code like,

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Here nameless (*I am not sure if I am using correct terminology*) object is used to call execute method of DownloadFilesTask's object.

Same I tried to use with C++ and following is code snippets.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Sam
{
public:
    void Access()
    {
        cout<<"Access";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    (new Sam())->Access; //for Access method intillesence is working fine

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run this code I get compilation error,

> Error 1   error C3867: 'Sam::Access': function call missing argument
>   list; use '&Sam::Access' to create a pointer to
>   member    c:\users\new-user\documents\visual studio
>   2012\projects\autoexample\autoexample\autoexample.cpp 18  1   autoExample

I do not understand meaning and reason of error. Is this type of code possible in C++?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you missing `()`?

Comment: You need to say `Access()` with parentheses. It is a function call. Of course, that doesn't fix the memory leak.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Got it.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ya you are correct. I am insane.

Comment: You're using Visual Studio, aren't you? I think it's IntelliSense doesn't add parentheses by default for some reason.

Comment: @W.K.S Yes you are right. It's my mistake. VS did it's job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As what's been said on the comments, you are lacking the parentheses needed to call the method.

```
Access()
//    ^^ These
```

However, a more important issue to be solved here is your use of `new`. Don't use it like you're using it now. By using it that way, you are creating a memory leak which you can never ever hope to reclaim because you would never have the chance to use `delete` on it<sup>[1]</sup> (unless you close your program...).

To use temporaries in C++, just use a stack-based, automatic storage object (in other words, normal objects):

```
  Sam().Access();
//^^^^^ This creates the temporary object
```

However, you must still be careful not to use that temporary in subsequent statements, a problem which is commonly encountered when mixing them with references.

```
Sam& bad_sam = Sam().I_Return_A_Reference_To_This_Object();
bad_sam.Access();   // Oh no!
```

In the above example, the temporary object created by `Sam()` will be destroyed at the end of the statement (hence being temporary). `bad_sam.Access();` would be illegal and would result in *undefined behavior*.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> <sub><sub>*Ahem* says the language lawyers. Of course you can use `delete this;`... To OP: don't!</sub></sub>